# openSuse - change PHP cli version

Tags: apache-httpd, compiling, php, source

I have built PHP 7.3.27 from source like this:

```
./configure --with-config-file-path=/etc/php7/cli \
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php7/cli \
 --with-openssl \
 --with-bz2 \
 --with-zlib \
 --with-bz2 \
 --with-sodium \
 --with-xsl \
 --with-readline \
 --enable-sockets \
 --enable-soap \
 --enable-mbstring \
 --enable-ftp \
 --enable-calendar \
 --enable-bcmath \
 --enable-pcntl \
 --prefix=$HOME/bin/php-latest
```

and executed `make && make install`, then I restarted apache2.

But if I execute `php -v` then the old php version is still showing.

What steps am I missing to change the PHP CLI version?

Comment: Is $HOME/bin/php-latest/bin in your $PATH?  That’s where you appear to have installed it.  (With —prefix)

Comment: No, it was not in my PATH. I added it now with `PATH=$PATH:~/$HOME/bin/php-latest/bin` it shows this now `/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin:/usr/local/modman:/root//root/bin/php-latest/bin` but If I execute `php -v` then I still get PHP 7.2.5

Comment: `/root//root/bin/php-latest/bin` looks weird. Have I did something wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: You said ~/$HOME/bin/php-latest/bin, not $HOME/bin/php-latest/bin.  Either use ~ or $HOME, not both.

Comment: How can I fix it? Is there a file where it is stored? I searched in etc/environment (?) i think, but my `php-latest` does not appear there.

Comment: When you ran `./configure`, you added: `--prefix=$HOME/bin/php-latest`.  That means that instead of putting the php executable in /usr/local/bin (which is `--prefix=/usr/local`), it put it in `$HOME/bin/php-latest/bin` (since everything lives within the "prefix").  Perhaps you didn't intend to do it that way, but that's what you wrote in the original post.  So, if you ran `./configure` as root, then it would be in `/root/bin/php-latest/bin`.

Comment: If you ran `./configure` as a different user than root, then it will be in that user's $HOME.